# how to convert .rm (RealPlayer Media) files to mp3 using NAudio?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I would like to convert .rm (RealPlayer Media) audio files to mp3, using c#, and NAudio library is preferable.

so if there are any suggestions on how to convert programaticly .rm to .mp3 will be appreciated.

Comment: You are describing a task instead of asking a question.  What RM decoder are you using and what kind of problem do you have with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAudio cannot decode RealPlayer Media or encode MP3, so it won't be much use to you.
[LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) is a good option for encoding MP3. I believe [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) might be able to decode RealAudio.